# Recursive Search Binary Search Tree with one parameter

Tags: c#, recursion, binary-search-tree

I am trying to search through a binary search tree using a recursive method in C#.

So far I am able to successfully execute this method using two parameters:

```
public bool Search(int value, Node start)
{
     if(start == null) {   
          return false;
     }

     else if(value == start.value) {
          return true;
     }

     else {
          if(value < start.value) {
                 Search(value, start.LeftChild.value);
          }
         
          else {
                 Search(value, start.RightChild.value);
          }
     }
}
```

However I would like to see if there's a way to use only one parameter such as using the following method signature:

`public bool Search(int value){}`

I also have the following that I can use to access the tree:

```
public class BinarySearchTree
{
     private Node<int> root;
     public Node<int> Root { get => root; set => root = value; }

     public BinarySearchTree()
     {
          this.root = null;
     }
}
```

Comment: That's not possible. How do you imagine to search trough a binary tree if you do not have the binary tree? To search trough a tree you of course need the tree or some starting point, like the node you have here, and the value you are searching for...

Comment: Hold on I will edit the question as I think it was not clear enough

Comment: Well you can just copy and paste the recursive binary search method you already have into the BinarySearchTree class and call it with the other method to just have the int value in the method header: public bool Search(int value) { return RecursiveBinarySearch(int value, this.Root); } But this kind of looks like a uni assignment where you maybe should get rid of the recursive method or something like that :)

Comment: Yes, it is kind of an assignment. The recursive method is obligatory. Thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: Then I would just copy and paste it into the class, rename it and call it int the "public bool Search(int value)" method like I did in the previous comment, eventually also make it private

Comment: If you got it to work you can copy and paste the solution and write the answer in here yourself :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public bool Search(int value)
{
     return SearchTree(value, root);

     bool SearchTree(int value, Node<int> start)
     {
          if(start == null)
               return false;
    
          else if(value == start.Value)
               return true;
    
          else 
          {
               if(value < start.Value)
                   return SearchTree(value, start.LeftChild);

               else
                   return SearchTree(value, start.RightChild);
          }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> if there's a way to use only one parameter such as using the following method signature:

sure. make it a method in Node class.

```
public class Node
{
    public Node LeftChild, RightChild;
    public int value;

    public bool Search(int value)
    {
         if (value == this.value) 
         {
              return true;
         }
         else 
         {
              if (value < this.value) 
              {
                  return this.LeftChild?.Search(value) ?? false;
              }
              else 
              {
                  return this.RightChild?.Search(value) ?? false;
              }
         }
    }
}
```

then for tree call it as `tree.Root.Search(0);`